# How To change Array stucture by user_id Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have array structure like this:

```
[
  {product:"A", user_id:1},
  {product:"B", user_id:2},
  {product:"C", user_id:1}
]
```

I want re-structure array by user_id like this:

```
[
  {user_id:1, product:["A","C"]},
  {user_id:2, product:["B"]}
]
```

How to change like that using php laravel, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: are you getting it from database in some query or it is just array

Comment: hae you tried something out and why it didnt work ? no one is conna code for you. And as @NurbekBoymurodov said, show us the query you used for it (with conditions and everything) since you tagged the question with laravel tag

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov that not from db, that from laravel session

Comment: what you've shown isnt valid php, are these meant to describe and array of arrays, or an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this would work:

NOTE: Im assuming your code is meant to describe an array of stdClass objects in php since what you've posted isnt valid php, if you really have an array of arrays, you'll need to adjust the syntax below to account for that.

```
<?php

$products = [
    (object) ['product' => "A", 'user_id' => 1],
    (object) ['product' => "B", 'user_id' => 2],
    (object) ['product' => "C", 'user_id' => 1]
];

$userProducts = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {

    // check if we have an object for this user id in our new array already 
    // and if so, just add this product to it
    $alreadyAdded = false;
    foreach ($userProducts as $userProduct) {
        if ($userProduct->user_id == $product->user_id) {
            $alreadyAdded = true;
            $userProduct->product[]= $product->product;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if no object for this user id in our new array yet, add one now
    if (!$alreadyAdded) {
        $newProduct = new \stdClass();
        $newProduct->user_id = $product->user_id;
        $newProduct->product = [$product->product];
        $userProducts[]= $newProduct;
    }
}

var_dump($userProducts);
```